# Why does O(n*n*n!) get simplified to O((n+2)!) when calculation big O

Tags: big-o, permutation

So I have have been reading the cracking the coding interview book and there is a problem where we’re  we have a function that does O(n* n* n!) work. The book then says  this can be expressed by O((n+2)!). It says Similarly O(n*n!)can be expressed by O((n+1)!). I looked in all rules if permutations and did not find any way to logically get there . My first step was cool I have O(n^2 +n!) now what?  I don’t know what steps to take next .

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions on SO should be when you want help with a specific coding problem. In the case of this question, it would seem more appropriate to consider heading over the [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and look for an answer or post a question over there.

Answer (score 0):

You already know (I think) that `n! = 1*2*3*...*n`. 
So `n*n*n! = 1*2*3*...*n*n*n`.

As n gets really big, adding 1 or 2 to a factor has a decreasingly significant effect. I'm no specialist but what matter with `O()` is either the power of n or, in our case, the number in the `()!` expression.
Which gets us to shorten this to `1*2*3*...*n*(n+1)*(n+2)=(n+2)!`.

Eventually, `O(n*n*n!)` can be expressed `O((n+2)!)`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculatee `x!` you do `x*(x-1)!` recursively until `x-1==1` so `x!==(x-1)*(x-2)*...*1` is O(n!). Therefore to do `x*x!` we have 
`(x-0)*(x-1)*...*1` which takes one extra call to our recursive function (but at the beginning, with large x value) i.e. `(x+1)!` iterations. Similarly, `(x-0)*(x-0)*(x-1)*(x-2)*...*1==x²*x!` requires `(x+2)!` function evaluations to compute, hence O((n+2)!) efficiency.